# use of Journal node in high availability

Tags: hadoop2, high-availability

What is the need of Journal node 
Why we configure three journal nodes in high availability. 
Is it only for replication?

Answer (score 0):

The Role of Journal nodes is to keep both the Namenodes in sync and avoid hdfs split brain scenario by allowing only Active NN to write into journals.

From [Apache Hadoop Documentations](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html)

Prior to Hadoop 2.0, the NameNode was a single point of failure (SPOF) in an HDFS cluster. Each cluster had a single NameNode, and if that machine was unavailable, the cluster on the whole would be unavailable until the NameNode was either restarted or started on a separate machine. In a classic HA cluster, two separate machines are configured as NameNodes. At any point, one of the NameNodes will be in Active state and the other will be in a Standby state. The Active NameNode is responsible for all client operations in the cluster, while the Standby is simply acting as a slave, maintaining enough state to provide a fast failover.

In order for the Standby node to keep its state coordinated with the Active node, both nodes communicate with a group of separate daemons called ‘JournalNodes’ (JNs). When any namespace modification is performed by the Active node, it logs a record of the changes made, in the JournalNodes. The Standby node is capable of reading the amended information from the JNs, and is regularly monitoring them for changes. As the Standby Node sees the changes, it then applies them to its own namespace. In case of a failover, the Standby will make sure that it has read all the changes from the JounalNodes before changing its state to ‘Active state’. This guarantees that the namespace state is fully synched before a failover occurs.

**JournalNode machines** - the machines on which you run the JournalNodes. The JournalNode daemon is relatively lightweight, so these daemons may reasonably be collocated on machines with other Hadoop daemons, for example NameNodes, the JobTracker, or the YARN ResourceManager. ***Note: There must be at least 3 JournalNode daemons, since edit log modifications must be written to a majority of JNs. This will allow the system to tolerate the failure of a single machine***. You may also run more than 3 JournalNodes, but in order to actually increase the number of failures the system can tolerate, you should run an odd number of JNs, (i.e. 3, 5, 7, etc.). Note that when running with N JournalNodes, the system can tolerate at most (N - 1) / 2 failures and continue to function normally.

Here is also some good external link about JournalNode

https://www.edureka.co/blog/namenode-high-availability-with-quorum-journal-manager-qjm/

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/27225/how-qjm-works-in-namenode-ha.html